# How to store values got from datatable into a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get Data table values and save them in a single string, where `dt.rows.Count` is more that 0.
[image]
I want get `menu_name`, `menu_Quantity` and store them into a single string where `email=ariffnaj@gmail.com`.
If this is possible, can you show how to do it, this code only save into string at first column only

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
                    ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
 string cartsql = "SELECT menu_name,menu_price,menu_quantity FROM cart where email=@email";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(cartsql, conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"].ToString());
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                string menuname = dtRow["menu_name"].ToString();
                string menuprice = dtRow["menu_price"].ToString();
                string menuquantity = dtRow["menu_quantity"].ToString();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to store that value in the datatable only or update the value in the database?

Comment: what do you mean by save into a single string? sample input + output please

Comment: Please see here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxsa23t6.aspx - for how you ought to be using datasets as a data access mechanism. Follow the "creating a simple data app" first. After you complete that tutorial you will know how to use datasets correctly and also be able to answer your own question

Comment: If you only need the string, then you don't need `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable`. Just call `ExecuteReader` on the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Why are you doing all your SQL queries manually in Asp.Net? 

Use Entity Framework and MVC. All your database calls should be wrapped in EF calls or LINQ calls. This is not only reinventing the wheel, you're introducing security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ScubaSteve 100% disagree. EF is an extra layer and thus its slower than native sql. Plus you can't leverage any DB engine specific feature nor can you fine tune your query to the optimal way which the engine likes the most

Comment: @Steve - Numbers or it doesn't matter. Show me that EF is slower. 

Just because something is wrapped, doesn't mean it's significantly slower. And yes, you can leverage DB engine features from EF.

You're seriously saying that all DB work in Asp.net should be unwrapped?

Comment: @ScubaSteve check out the official MS blog post about performance(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2008/03/27/ado-net-entity-framework-performance-comparison/). if you are only running that query once then the result is negligible. But if you have to run that hundred times every second then raw sql is a better bet. As for the DB engine feature, try to use the `OVER(PARTITION BY [Column]) AS something` feature in EF

Comment: @ScubaSteve or a simpler example.  `DELETE FROM [SomeTable] OUTPUT DELETED.ID; ` you would need to call store procedure with raw Sql in it or else you can't get it to work with EF.

Comment: But to, in-general, say that someone shouldn't use EF? That might be good advice in *some* high-performance cases, but that's bad advice in the general sense.

Comment: I do use some raw SQL, we have a bit shifting algorithm that allows us to poll some data very quickly. But that's the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a `SqlDataReader` instead of `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable`. This is easier, if you only want to retrieve some values. To build the string I use a `StringBuilder`, as it manages the resources better than string concatenation would.

```
public string GetCartStringForEMail(string email)
{
    const string sql = "SELECT menu_name, menu_quantity FROM cart WHERE email=@email";

    string connectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) {
            sb.Append(reader.GetString(0))
                .Append(", ")
                .AppendLine(reader.GetInt32(1).ToString());
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note that the using-statements automatically close the connection and release the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can try coalesce function:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @str = (COALESCE(@str + ';', '') + CONCAT('Menu:', menu_name, ', Quantity:', menu_quantity)) 
FROM cart WHERE email=@email
SELECT @str as output
```

And then use:`String str = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`